# Event Delegation in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, event-delegation

Is there any way to add event delegation from outer body elements into shadow elements?

For instance, I want a special function to fire whenever someone clicks an `anchor` with `class="special"`.

Normally (in jquery):

`$('body').on('click', 'a.special', myFunction);`

However, this doesn't seem possible using the shadow DOM, at least with everything I've tried. Do I really need to add these handlers to every instance of `a.special` as they appear in some template?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can still use event delegation with custom elements:

```
$('body').on('click', 'my-element', myFunction);
```

The difference is that the event will look like it came from my-element instead of an `a.special` inside of your element's shadow dom. That's because the [event model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events) does retargeting to hide the implementation details of your shadow dom.

You can also setup listeners inside your element that fire an event when `a.special` is clicked: http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#utilizing-event-delegation

For something more sophisticated, check out the [Communication & Message Passing](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#using-ltcore-signalsgt) on the Polymer site. Particularly, `<core-signals>` can be used for a pubsub-like pattern.

Comment: Note that `event.path` can give you more information about the undisguised target. This is a problem solver, but it breaks encapsulation, so use it sparingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So it looks like I cannot really have a global event delegation pattern with the shadow dom? I see the example you've given and have already read through all the website's docs, but it seems that (especially with *nested templates*) I'll have to conform to the polymer approach and change my way of thinking...@ScottMiles: can you explain path? I see it in the event object but 1) cannot find any docs on the path property, and 2) its just an empty node list (for me)